# Get sum of a column in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose i have the table below and i want to add the column `Credits` to get its sum

```
<table id="tbl_semester11">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Semester 1</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Module Code</th>
             <th>Module Name</th>
             <th>Credits</th>
             <th>Module %</th>
             <th>Grade</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>MGMT1101C</td>
             <td>Management Seminar</td>
             <td id="txtcredit112" class="sum">3</td>
             <td><input type="number" id="txtpercentage112" min="40" max="100" onchange="process([1,1,2,5]);"></td>
             <td id="txtgrade112">D</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="alt">
             <td>HCA1105C</td>
             <td>Computer Architecture</td>
             <td id="txtcredit113" class="sum">4</td>
             <td><input type="number" id="txtpercentage113" min="40" max="100" onchange="process([1,1,3,5]);"></td>
             <td id="txtgrade113">D</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>PROG1115C</td>
             <td>Object Oriented Software Development I</td>
             <td id="txtcredit114" class="sum">4</td>
             <td><input type="number" id="txtpercentage114" min="40" max="100" onchange="process([1,1,4,5]);"></td>
             <td id="txtgrade114">D</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="alt">
             <td>MATH1103C</td>
             <td>Decision Mathematics</td>
             <td id="txtcredit115" class="sum">3</td>
             <td><input type="number" id="txtpercentage115" min="40" max="100" onchange="process([1,1,5,5]);"></td>
             <td id="txtgrade115">D</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>ITE1107C</td>
             <td>Language and Communication Seminar</td>
             <td id="txtcredit116" class="sum">3</td>
             <td><input type="number" id="txtpercentage116" min="40" max="100" onchange="process([1,1,6,5]);"></td>
             <td id="txtgrade116">D</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="al">
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td bgcolor="#b3ffb3"><b>S.P.A</b></td>
             <td bgcolor="#4dff4d" id="spa11">40.7</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is my JS

```
function getsum(arr) {
    var sum = 0;
    var tbl_id = 'tbl_semester' + arr[0] + arr[1];
    $('#' + tbl_id + '.sum').each(function () {
        sum += +(this).text()||0;
    });
    return sum;
```

`arr` is the same parameter as process i.e `[1,1,3,5]`.The problem is that sum always returns 0

Comment: missing `$` , `sum += +$(this).text()||0;`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Ahh ... i missed that but even now sum returns 0

Comment: You can `reduce` this with normal JavaScript for a shorter function. `let sum = [...document.querySelectorAll("#"+tbl_id)].reduce((x,y) => x.textContent + y.textContent);` Granted this is an ES6 spread and arrow syntax, a reduce is a better way to sum up an array (in my opinion)

Comment: and missing a space at `$('#' + tbl_id + '.sum').each...`, should be like this `$('#' + tbl_id + ' .sum').each...`

Comment: `var tbl_id = 'tbl_semester' + arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2];` , missing `arr[2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. If you want to select children with the `.sum` class, you should add a space between parent and children. Your function should be:

```
function getsum(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  var tbl_id = 'tbl_semester' + arr[0] + arr[1];
  $('#' + tbl_id + ' .sum').each(function () {
      sum += parseInt($(this).text())||0;
  });
  return sum;
}
```

Also, I used `parseInt()` because `.text()` returns a string. That way you are sure to have a `NaN` value or an actual integer.

Comment: Answer would be even better if you explained the need of parseInt :)